# Can't read header parameters from WebGate response using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, oam

For example this is my VM WARE WEBGATE login page.
[image: 1]

After entering Valid Credentials it will Valid Under OAM (oracle access manager) and it will return headers in response.

Now, If the user is valid it will redirect to another page.

But, I can't see the header parameters  in response what the WebGate returning

This is my Code:

```
app.factory('mainHttpInterceptor' ,
        function($rootScope, $q, $location) {`enter code here`
    console.log("in the authInterceptor------000000");
    return{
        request:function(config) {
        console.log(config.headers);
        return config;
        },

    response: function(response){

    /*  if (typeof response.headers != null) {
           console.log(response.headers);
            return response;

        }   */
    console.log('in the hhtp interceptor');
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers']= true;
    console.log(response.headers());
    console.log(response);
    return response;
    },

    responseError: function(rejection){
        console.log('Failed with', rejection.status, 'status');
        if( rejection.status ==403){
            $location.url('/login');
        }
        else if( rejection.status ==404){
            console.log("nothing is there----------->");
            /*$state.go('login');*/
        }

        return $q.reject(rejection);
    }

};
        })
        app.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {  
            $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
            /*Access-Control-Allow-Credentials == true;*/
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = true;
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('mainHttpInterceptor');
}]);
```

[image: console.log(config.headers)]

What, Should i do to to get those header parameters into my code.

Comment: What kind of header you want? The OAM give you the headers that you configured in OAM Admin Console and if you access to protected page.

Comment: Actually, they are appending some headers with some key value pairs in response.Its just a Gate in order to access my application based on the header parameters what they are returning in response.

Comment: `'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'` is a response header...not a request header

Comment: You can append header configuring the authorization policy in OAM